# How to recover my account if I forgot my e-mail address?

Tags: support, login, openid

I forgot my Stack Overflow account and I have logged out of my Gmail account - so I have no other option to get back to my Stack Overflow account. So I created this post to ask this question.

Is there any way I can know the e-mail address of this account? I have forgotten my e-mail address since I have created so many e-mail address already. Here is my account

https://stackoverflow.com/users/2450045/belmark-caday

If I know the e-mail address I can login again to my Gmail and it automatically logs me in to Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fill out [this form](https://stackoverflow.com/contact/defunct) to request a merge on the basis of a lost OpenID.

Alternatively, email team@stackoverflow.com with as many details as you can specify. Email addresses are privately identifying information, so they can't be simply released unless you can prove to a reasonable degree that you own the older account.

Comment: I think it is team@stackexchange.com

Comment: @Lucifer: They're the same. team@se forwards to team@so

Comment: i have this error when i fill the form `

Oops! There was a problem with your help submission:

    Other Profile Link should be of the form http://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/<id>/<display-name>

`

Comment: @user2492415: Try the link now. I accidentally gave you the MSO one

Comment: Done, I already sent a message to them, how long does it take for them to reply?

Comment: @user2492415: Well, most will be asleep right now and Tim Post doesn't seem to be around, so it may take a day (or two).